# Php Readiness check failed due to different version of php

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I just updated php to `PHP 7.1.12-3+ubuntu17.10.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli) (built: Dec 14 2017 15:40:13) ( NTS )`and when i try to readiness check for magento2, i am getting error that PHP Version Check Your PHP version is `7.1.11-0ubuntu0.17.10.1. The required PHP version is ~5.6.5|7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6. Hide detail`

I got that it allows on these versions
    http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/prereq/php-ubuntu.html

I have tried different solutions given 
    http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/prereq/php-ubuntu.html

```
sudo apt-get -y update
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt-get -y update
sudo apt-get install -y php7.0 libapache2-mod-php7.0 php7.0 php7.0-common php7.0-gd php7.0-mysql php7.0-mcrypt php7.0-curl php7.0-intl php7.0-xsl php7.0-mbstring php7.0-zip php7.0-bcmath php7.0-iconv php7.0-soap
```

I have no idea, how to install 2 version of php or if i remove php7 and install php5 then whether any new issue will come. please help me to resolve the issue..I am using Ubuntu 17.10 & Magento 2.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install php version `7.0.6–7.0.x` if you want to use latest version of PHP supported by magento 2. As magento 2 readiness check clearly dictates that your php version is not supported. Please downgrade you PHP version.

**It seems like you have installed php 7.0 version but forgot to disable 7.1 and enable 7.0.**
Please enter these commands after php 7.0 installation.

```
$ sudo a2dismod php7.1
$ sudo a2enmod php7.0
$ sudo service apache2 restart
```

Answer (score 0):

If you see here your version of PHP is not supported yet. http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/prereq/php-ubuntu.html Please degrade to lower version.

Please refer below link to downgrade the PHP version.

https://tecadmin.net/downgrade-php-on-ubuntu/